# extract .rar files to a specific directory in php

Tags: php, rar

I want to extract **.rar file** not **.zip file** using php 
I followed this example in php manual

[php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/rararchive.open.php)

the problem in this tutorial is not extract the files to directory,
it prints the content of the file to browser.

Comment: Make sure you have [installed](http://php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php) the plugin. Then look up [at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14555730/how-to-extract-rar-archive-files-and-folders-using-php-in-windows) :)

Comment: yes i did, php_rar.dll

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to extract the files from the archive with the [RarEntry::extract](http://php.net/manual/en/rarentry.extract.php) method.

So something like:

```
$archive = RarArchive::open('archive.rar');
$entries = $archive->getEntries();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
    $entry->extract('/extract/to/this/path');
}
$archive->close();
```

Comment: does this overwrites files? been searching for 2 hours, haven't found, even in php.net nor here. Can't test it myself for some reasons.

Comment: Is this fit to new rar format? I got some rar that only winrar can parse but 7zip can't.

Answer (score 0):

btw: `extract` offers overwrite as third parameter (second being an array of paths to extract)

Answer (score 0):

in Laravel to Extract rar file

**first:**
add this library to **composer.json** file

[image]

**Second:**
in controller to use it

```
use RarArchive;
```

**Last:**

```
$archive = RarArchive::open(public_path('storage/') . $pathFile);
$entries = $archive->getEntries();
foreach ($entries as $entry) {
  $entry->extract(public_path('storage/project/newfolder1'));
}
$archive->close();
```

Comment: updating your screenshot will improve the quality of your answer