# Convert .cbr file to .zip file in php

Tags: php, zip, unzip, php-ziparchive

I want to extract a .cbr archive (digital comics format) content with a php script.
I searched for a php method to unzip archive and the simpliest I found is the ZipArchive. I know (maybe is incorrect) that the way for converting from cbr to zip is simply renaming the archive file. Although WinRar can open it, the script doesn't work. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

rename("comic.cbr", "comic.zip");
$path = "comic.zip";

$zip = new ZipArchive;

if ($zip->open($path) === true) {

    for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) {
        $zip->extractTo('.', array($zip->getNameIndex($i)));
    }  

    $zip->close();           
}

?>
```

Comment: seems that .cbr is just rar archive. try open it as regular .rar file

Comment: rar is not zip, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36914245/extract-rar-files-to-a-specific-directory-in-php - unpack it then zip it back up.

Comment: @AlexBender should I install a php library for opening Rar Files?

Comment: I'm not a php dev, but according to this page no, you don't need it.
http://php.net/manual/en/rarentry.extract.php

Comment: I don't think RarEntry comes with PHP - you need to install a PHP Extension. I'd stick with a library if you can find one .

Comment: Your need PECL, but you could use something like https://github.com/dmamontov/rararchiver#rararchiverextractto..., id look into doing it with shell_exec and `unrar e` then `zip`, most likely a 1 liner.

Comment: First stop: https://packagist.org/?q=rar&p=0&dFR%5Btags%5D%5B0%5D=rar